# grep -m1 function in Perl,

Tags: perl, grep

For a line that has `CASPER US_PARENT` I need to capture the time and the rootid, from the first line of the group and stop.

I need to skip the rest of the lines that contain the same root order id as the first instance of `CASPER US_PARENT` and find the first line that contains
the same rootid but the different apptype `YIGYO`. Then I need to compare the `CAPSER US_PARENT` transaction time and the `YIGYO` transaction
time, and if the `CASPER US_PARENT` is earlier than `YIGYO, print the whole` CAPSER US_PARENT` line.

#### timecompareperl.pl.viewCASPER

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

use Time::Local ;
use List::Util ; 

#open (my $fh,'<:encoding(UTF-8)',$ARGV[0]) ;
#while (my $line = <$fh> ) {
while (my $line = <DATA> ) {

    my ( $msgcat, $transtme, $rootid, $clntid, $aptype, $evntyp ) = split(/,/, $line);

    if ( "$msgcat" eq "CASPER US_PARENT" ) {
        my $first_rootid = first { m{ $rootid }x } $line ;
        print "$first_rootid\n" 
        sleep 1 ;
    }
}

#msgcategory,transacttime,rootordid,clordid,apptype,eventtype

__DATA__



CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T13:58:34.525,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojwf""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:31.300,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojwf""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:31.300,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojwf""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:34.928,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojwf""",CASPER US,AR
PARENT,2017.12.21T16:03:37.000,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""A0318DC7-0443-410C-86FD-16D2989590B9""",YIGYO US,AR
PARENT,2017.12.21T16:03:37.806,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""FA0A130A-DB35-4C13-B70A-0DEFFBF420FE""",YIGYO US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T13:58:34.552,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojuz""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:31.303,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojuz""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:31.303,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojuz""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:34.936,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojuz""",CASPER US,AR
PARENT,2017.12.21T16:03:35.369,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""7D695BC4-E771-4427-873E-CBC60DA09AD9""",YIGYO US,AR
PARENT,2017.12.21T16:03:35.793,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""BB3543B9-1581-4613-9781-4022DFDABA82""",YIGYO US,AR
```

Bash has a `grep -m/#/` where it will find a certain number of matches and then stop. I don't see one in the Perl `grep` function. I see something like the "grep one and done" behaviour in `List::Util`, but it is not working.

Comment: I would not use `grep` for this. It's well-suited for searching text for a pattern, but poorly suited for grouping and joining. Instead you'll either need to read the entire file into a data structure and manipulate that, or make an FSM that processes the file on the fly. Perl libraries to parse CSV are a dime a dozen.

Comment: Okay, so what is your question? Does your program work? Please don't decorate data like that: we need to see what the *exact* input is.

Comment: @TypeIA - thanks - so if I put this through Text::CSV that is a finite state machine ?

Comment: `Text::CSV` is for when there's quoting happening. Your data looks simple enough that `split /,/` will be sufficient.

Comment: @Borodin - I will not decorate the date like that in the future - thank you for your help.

Comment: @Sobrique: On the contrary, the fields like `"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221"""` are strings enclosed in *significant quotes* corresponding to a data value of `"WMCE792e35c0992e:171221"`. It's best to use a module to make sense of stuff like this, otherwise when *would* you use one?

Comment: @Borodin - I have these modules available at my place of employment Text-CSV_PP, Text-CSV_PP-Iterator, Text-CSV_XS and Text-CSV. Getting anything else installed is going to be difficult

Comment: Any and all of those are fine. Start by using `Text::CSV` to replace your `split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, given what you've asked, something like this would appear to do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Data::Dumper;

chomp( my @header = split /,/, <DATA> );

my %orders;

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   my ( $msgcat, $transtme, $rootid, $clntid, $aptype, $evntyp ) = split /,/;

   $rootid =~ s/\"//g;
   $orders{$rootid}{$aptype} //= $transtme;
}

print Dumper \%orders;

foreach my $order ( keys %orders ) {

   foreach my $apid ( keys %{ $orders{$order} } ) {
      $orders{$order}{$apid} =~ s/\.(\d+)$//;
      my $msec = $1;
      print "$msec\n";

      my $time_convert =
        Time::Piece->strptime( $orders{$order}{$apid}, "%Y.%m.%dT%H:%M:%S" );
      $orders{$order}{$apid} = ( $time_convert->epoch * 1000 ) + $msec;
   }

   print "Time delta  for $order is: ",
     $orders{$order}{"YIGYO US"} - $orders{$order}{"CASPER US"}, "ms\n";
   ## in your case - look for a negative 'delta' as your test for comparison.
}


__DATA__
msgcategory,transacttime,rootordid,clordid,apptype,eventtype
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T13:58:34.525,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojwf""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:31.300,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojwf""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:31.300,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojwf""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:34.928,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojwf""",CASPER US,AR
PARENT,2017.12.21T16:03:37.000,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""A0318DC7-0443-410C-86FD-16D2989590B9""",YIGYO US,AR
PARENT,2017.12.21T16:03:37.806,"""WMCE792e35c0992e:171221""","""FA0A130A-DB35-4C13-B70A-0DEFFBF420FE""",YIGYO US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T13:58:34.552,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojuz""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:31.303,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojuz""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:31.303,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojuz""",CASPER US,AR
CASPER US_PARENT,2017.12.21T16:05:34.936,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""PUSA17122100ojuz""",CASPER US,AR
PARENT,2017.12.21T16:03:35.369,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""7D695BC4-E771-4427-873E-CBC60DA09AD9""",YIGYO US,AR
PARENT,2017.12.21T16:03:35.793,"""WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221""","""BB3543B9-1581-4613-9781-4022DFDABA82""",YIGYO US,AR
```

It parse the timestamps, converts them to epoch - there's an extra bit of handling for milliseconds - if that's unimportant, then you can simplify a bit.

And it gives a result like:

```
Time delta for WMCE792e35c0992e:171221 is: 7502475ms
Time delta for WMCE14e8b1aab603:171221 is: 7500817ms
```

You'd be able to check for that delta being negative as your test case.

Comment: There's no need to `chomp` all of the header fields

Comment: As discussed above, it's ugly to leave the data escaped after you split it into fields. You have no way of knowing whether there may be an embedded comma in any of the data.

Comment: Assigning to `$msec` should be conditional on the preceding substitution succeeding.